# Send a link with with scroll directions

Tags: browser, scrolling

There is a way to send a link with scroll to specific place in the destination page.

More particular, I want to reference the link https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794, but this is a really long page, so I want to send a link that will lead to the place in the page I want to refer (like the option to add `&t=10s` to a youtube links in order to link to a specific place in the video, but with scroll).

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for an HTML anchor. It is specified by adding a `#` at the end of your URL. The document you linked to, doesn't have any anchors. You can't do what you are asking.

Comment: Oh, for future reference, How do I recognise anchor? And how I add the # to refer to the place in the page I want to refer?

Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is if the page has a "table of contents" that you can click.  Just copy and paste the link from the table of contents to the specific section of the page.